# Dropdown populated by dynamic data

Tags: sdl-tridion

I am trying to develop some Pages in SDL Tridion 2011. One of the most frustrating aspects is the creation of a dropdown element with dynamic data.

I am trying to create a dropdown that I want to dynamically populate it by a list of SDL Folders. On change event of the dropdown I want to change the displaying content, by loading the first Component/Article found inside each Folder.

Comment: Is this a page that interacts with the Content Manager? I assume so, given you mention Folders...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what your actual problem is, and what you already tried ?
Based on the info my guess is that you'll want to create a .NET web page which connects to the CM using core services (more info on that subject here http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9E4840FE-F97A-461A-8F33-179791ECE083). Using this, you can fetch a series of folders, and on selection of a folder, get component data from that selected folder

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, instead of building your own solution, I would recommend, you should use the existing community solutions and modify them to your need.

One such community project similar to your need is the **Item Selector** created by Bart and is available for download along with the code from [HERE](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx)

This is quite a clean and highly configurable code which uses a Tree View data structure instead of the Drop Down and lists all publications and then folders and then all elements inside the folders - You can configure and further choose to modify the code as per your need.

If you still want to implement your own solution, then you should be doing following:

- Use the Core Service and fetch all folders information using it
- Bind your drop down with the Folders information
- On Drop Down change event, again call the Core Service to fetch the Items/Component or whatever you need and display it as per your need